# Changing default zoom level for VIEWING documents in MS Word 2002

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to get MS Word 2002 to open all documents at 100% zoom. I modified normal.dot, thinking that would do it, but that appears to only be for documents I create. I want to see all existing documents at 100% zoom. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What what I can see simple the answer is "no".

Opening a new blank doc and tweaking that will modify the settings in `normal.dot` for future *new* files. From your question it's clear you've already identified this, but I mention for completeness.

The only useful suggestions I could find about setting the zoom on *existing* files involved creating an `AutoOpen` macro in `normal.dot` to set the zoom - since (almost) every `.doc` should derive from `normat.dot` they should trigger the macro when you open them and zoom as required.

*Personally*, I'm not sure I like this idea, but it's all I've managed to find...